# Ordering posts by custom fields

Tags: custom-field

good day, quick question, I have a site that pulls posts from certain category, basically the code to see how I call those posts is as follows:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h2>Ultimos Estrenos Nintendo Wii</h2>
<?php query_posts('cat=99&order=DSC&showposts=11&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) :  ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumb-small' ); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p><?php _e('No posts were found. Sorry!'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?></p>
<br /><br />
<a href="http://bluegames.com.ve/category/nintendo-wii/" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">VER TODOS LOS ESTRENOS</a>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm using order=DSC to order posts but the client has a custom field that is a code, they want to order those posts using that custom field, but I'm not sure how to achieve that, I call that custom field using this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Codigo de Pelicula', true); ?>
```

But I don't know how to order those posts using that custom field, so, asking, someone with that kind of past experience that can help with?

Comment: See [Codex: WP_Query - Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). And always add all relevant code to the question, instead of linking to a external resource.

Comment: Please add your code to your question. Most users will simply skip your post as it is really annoying and time wasting having to open multiple screens o read just one post :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a code I'm using ina website that I'm creating for a client. Maybe it can point you in the right direction:

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'billboard_evento',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,                            
    'meta_key' => 'fecha-inicio', //Declaring wich meta key I want to use
    'orderby' => 'fecha-inicio', //Ordering the queried elements by meta value 
    'order'  => 'ASC',

    'meta_query' => array(  //Querying by meta field
        array(
            'key' => 'fecha-inicio', //meta field name for an event start date
            'value' => $current_date, // Setting the value to current date
            'compare' => '>=', // Comparing current date with event start date
            'type' => 'DATE', //Type of value
        ),
    )
); 
$query_eventos = new WP_query($args);
```

Comment: Hola Eduardo gracias, the thing is, I'm trying to add that code to my call, here's what I am using: